# gedit looks strange ("ugly") on Ubuntu/WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gedit

I used gedit in the past and know it like this:

[image: Correct version of gedit]

On my freshly installed Ubuntu 18 (WSL) it looks like this (when I just call `/usr/bin/gedit` on the command line with an xserver running):

[image: Ugly version of gedit]

It drives me nuts because it looks so ugly and inconvenient.
I tried to delete `~/.cache` but no success.

Is there a way to fix this to the original design?

Comment: Because Ubuntu has many themes which are applied upon Gnome application e.g. gedit. Try to find those themes and customization settings and install those in Ubuntu in WSL.

Comment: My Ubuntu 18 is in a true Virtual Machine, but Gedit looks like your second screenshot. The tools you need are condensed into the little 3-bar icon top right.